Problems with second order predicates
It is said that there is a problem with second order predicates (=SOP). They define the SOP Common as

Common(P), iff $\exists x\exists y (x\neq y \wedge Px \wedge Py).$

Then they observe that property of being common has the property of being common, i.e. Common(Common) is true in second order logic (=SOL).
My problem is, provided that a SOP takes first order predicates as arguments, how "Common(Common)" is a sentence of SOL? Shouldn't we pass to third order logic in order to see SOP as arguments?

It is said where? Who is "they"? Common(Common) is indeed ill-typed.

@NaïmFavier I read it yesterday here https://faculty.washington.edu/smcohen/120/SecondOrder.pdf
So my last argument is ok, right?

Yes, but note that even third-order logic won't allow you to say Common(Common). You'd need the type of Common to involve itself in a negative position, which is a source of logical inconsistency as you can express the Y combinator that way. The best you can hope for is Common³(Common²).

@NaïmFavier If I define a third order predicate, say, COMMON, using the second order definition analogously (COMMON instead Common and x, y for SOP) , it seems enough.

Yes, that's what I mean: you have COMMON(Common), not Common(Common) or COMMON(COMMON).

"My problem is, provided that a SOP takes first order predicates as arguments" - after skimming the linked paper, it seems that they start out by not making that restriction (arguments are not first order predicates, just predicates), and then the rest of the discussion is about what that means, what problems it leads to, and if things should be formulated differently.

@FilipMilovanović My question was about the necessity of third order logic for something like Common$(\cdot)$. I didn't intend to criticize the paper -I wouldn't have mentioned it, if Naim hadn't ask. However I think that that the paper states clearly about SOL things -but I cannot check it right now and it is not about our task.

There are various definitions of second-order systems of logic; see Carl Mummert's answer for one. All in all, each one has to distinguish relation (and possibly, function) variables from individual variables.
The referred text does not do this and treats the subject-matter like untyped lambda calculus. But I think, it ought to be given a sympathetic reading and regarded as to explicate the difficulties an untyped formalism would give rise to.
